# How node_access tag works with query?

Tags: 8, nodes

I'm not able to understand the use and role of the node_access tag. I used the [Node View permission](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_view_permissions) module to restrict the access to the *article* content type for anonymous users.

Now I have created an auto-complete search box that searches node titles. This is the query I used.

```
$query = \Drupal::entityquery('node');
$query->condition('title', trim($search));
$query->condition('status', 1);
$query->addTag('node_access');
$nids = $query->execute();
$nodes = Node::loadMultiple($nids);
```

I don't want this search box to search titles that belong to the *article* content type, and I used the *node_access* tag.

Will this tag serves my purpose here or is there any other approach to achieve the same?

Comment: Node access checks if a certain user is allowed to see a node. It not for filtering entity types (unles the user should not see those, but you did not say that). Use a condition for the type instead.

Answer (score 2):

No, it will not serve for the purpose you have in mind. It checks the currently logged-in user has view access to the node, which means that if the currently logged-in user is the user #1, it will see every node, including the ones that aren't published, and independently from the content type.

As @Neograph734 says, you should not use that tag to filter out nodes basing on their content type. If you want to filter the result by content type, you should use a line like `$query->condition('type', 'article');` to built the query.